# Apache webserver logs rotation issue

Tags: apache, unix

i have the virtual hosting configuration in apache as follows.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.org
DocumentRoot /www/example
ServerAdmin tin@ex.com
ErrorLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /www/logs/example/error_log.%Y%m%d 7776000"
CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /www/logs/example/access_log.%Y%m%d 7776000" common
</VirtualHost>
```

For this setup respctive logs are generating as follows,which i have issues.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root   1K   Jun 07 02:17 error_log.20140701-20140707.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     0 Jun 07 02:17 error_log.20140707
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root   17K Jun 07 02:28 access_log.20140701-20140707.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     0 Jun 07 02:28 access_log.20140707
```

Here i have 0 bytes log files which is not keeping today logs content. what will be cause for getting 0 bytes log files for this setup. How to make configuration 
which works to keep the today logs file content without 0 bytes.

Thank you .